# how to add html element for every three result in foreach using php?

Tags: php

I would like to add ul li html element for every 3 results in foreach using php. I have tried with the following method. but i am not getting the exact results. please advise on this

```
 Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [category_name] => Architect ) 
 [1] => stdClass Object ( [category_name] => Doors & Windows ) 
 [2] => stdClass Object ( [category_name] => Garage Doors ) 
 [3] => stdClass Object ( [category_name] => Home Inspection ) )



      <?php 
                    $i=0;
                     //$arrays = array_chunk($get_business_cat_details, 3);
                    foreach($get_business_cat_details as $key=> $cat_name){                                                         

                                //echo " <ul style='margin-top: 20px;'><li><a href='#'>".ucwords($cat_name->category_name) ."</a></li>";
                                if($i%3==0){

                                    echo "<ul><li><a href='#'>".ucwords($cat_name->category_name) ."</a></li></ul>";

                                }else{
                                    echo "<ul><li><a href='#'>".ucwords($cat_name->category_name) ."</a></li></ul>";
                                }
                                $i++;

                        }


                    ?>
```

Output:

```
 Power -- Wash --  Cleaning Paint 

East Valley --  Central/South Phx --  West Valley
```

Comment: Post your array along with expected output. You can use `for($i = 0; $i < count($your_array); $i += 3;){ //your code}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below code.

```
    <?php

$i = 0;
//$arrays = array_chunk($get_business_cat_details, 3);
foreach ($get_business_cat_details as $key => $cat_name) {

    //echo " <ul style='margin-top: 20px;'><li><a href='#'>".ucwords($cat_name->category_name) ."</a></li>";
    if($i==0) {
        $get_style="style='margin-top: 20px;'";
    } else {
        $get_style="";
    }

    if ($i % 3 == 0) {
        echo "<ul ".$get_style." >";
    }

    echo "<li><a href='#'>" . ucwords($cat_name->category_name) . "</a></li>";

    $i++;
    if ($i % 3 == 0 && $i != 0) {
        echo "</ul>";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: @markatteteam Can you please send me what type of result you get ?

Comment: Yes getting the result  but how to add margin-top:20px for the first results alone

Comment: @markatteteam did you mean add this  "<ul style='margin-top: 20px;'>" only for first result (first <ul>) ?

Comment: @markatteteam Replace this code please

<?php

$i = 0;
//$arrays = array_chunk($get_business_cat_details, 3);
foreach ($get_business_cat_details as $key => $cat_name) {

    //echo " <ul style='margin-top: 20px;'><li><a href='#'>".ucwords($cat_name->category_name) ."</a></li>";
 if($i==0) {
  $get_style="style='margin-top: 20px;'";
 } else {
  $get_style="";
 }
 
    if ($i % 3 == 0) {
        echo "<ul ".$get_style." >";
    }

    echo "<li><a href='#'>" . ucwords($cat_name->category_name) . "</a></li>";

    $i++;
    if ($i % 3 == 0 && $i != 0) {
        echo "</ul>";
    }
}
?>

Comment: @markatteteam Sorry, by mistake entered press so comment was post. Please see my answer also i have made changed.

Comment: yes now working but could you explain to me what i did wrong in the above code

Comment: @markatteteam yes sure. We have put first condition for start <ul> and same condition at the end but it not apply when our loop as 0 and we need to add style only once so we put condition and on other put that variable blank, 

If this answer usefull for you please upvote.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be what your looking for. Since your initial  tag is in your loop every result would essentially be a complete list. By removing the  from the loop you can close the tag and open a new one dynamically in the loop.

```js
    <? php
    $i = 0;
  echo "<ul>";
   foreach($get_business_cat_details as $key => $cat_name) {
     if ($i % 3 == 0) {
       echo "</ul><ul>";
     }
     echo "<li><a href='#'>".ucwords($cat_name - > category_name).
       "</a></li>";
     $i++;

   }
echo "</ul>";
    ?>
```